# How to install mail server on vps (digitalocean)

Tags: email, server, sendmail, digital-ocean, mailgun

I need send and receive e-mails. I need configure on Digital Ocean Vps a Mail server.

I need a how to or any recommendation about it. I think I will have to create a database to store messages.

**I have seen**:

**Mailgun**: I have created an account and created dns records Mx and Txt but Its not verified yet. So I can't receive email.

**SendMail**: I think it's I have already installed but I don't know how to send and receive email from hello@domain.com

**Postfix**: I've tried to install didn't work it

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailservers are complex beasts of software. Installing your own might be a bad idea, unless you're willing to invest time to

- make it secure
- protect it against spam and viruses
- back up your emails
- understand topics such as DMARC and TLS and greylisting
- ...

See [why you may not want to run your own mail server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/why-you-may-not-want-to-run-your-own-mail-server) for more information.

Maybe you could use an email provider instead? [Google Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/) is a great choice :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an open-source solution 
[Mail-in-a-Box](https://mailinabox.email/) lets you become your own mail service provider in a few easy steps. It’s sort of like making your own gmail, but one you control from top to bottom.

Technically, Mail-in-a-Box turns a fresh cloud computer into a working mail server.